# How to deal with NaN in large arrays using swift

Tags: swift, nan, accelerate

I am using the swift accelerate APIs to process some data. However a few of these data points contain NaN values (result of trying to divide a zero value).

My question is can I easily deal with this using any inbuilt swift function? I am looking at replacing all values of NaN with zero values so that I can still further process these large data sets without an error.

Comment: If your arrays are very large maybe it is best to handle those NaN elements ony by one as you process the data

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `map` method to transform all `NaN` values to 0 and all other values to themselves:

```
let arrayWithoutNaNs = yourArray.map { $0.isNaN ? 0 : $0 }
```

Since your arrays are long, you might also want consider doing this lazily by adding a `.lazy` before `.map`.